# How to calculate the trend line

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to calculate a trend line, according to the formula I got from this site:

http://classroom.synonym.com/calculate-trendline-2709.html

I have done the trend line in High Charts by adding the code and passing the values dynamically and this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="regression.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {        
        var sourceData = [
          [0, 99.75], [1, 99.77],
          [2, 99.78], [3, 99.84],
          [4, 99.82], [5, 99.82],
          [6, 99.76], [7, 99.78],
          [8, 99.8], [9, 99.65],
          [10, 99.94], [11, 99.8]
        ];

        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'RNA',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Outage Reasons',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '21-Jul-14', '22-Jul-14', '23-Jul-14',
                    '24-Jul-14', '25-Jul-14', '26-Jul-14', '27-Jul-14', '28-Jul-14', '29-Jul-14']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Percent'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                //align: 'right',
                //verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
                data: sourceData
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                marker: { enabled: false },
                /* function returns data for trend-line */
                data: (function() {
                  return fitData(sourceData).data;
                })()
            }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            }
      });
});


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<script src="exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

This is graph that gets generated:

[image]

What I would like to know is:

1. How the values are calculating the values according to the formula and what are the values
2. How the trend line is plotting on the graph.
3. I know the dates on the x-axis isn't calculate with formula.
4. I have done calculate according to the values

   [0, 99.75], [1, 99.77],
   [2, 99.78], [3, 99.84],
   [4, 99.82], [5, 99.82],
   [6, 99.76], [7, 99.78],
   [8, 99.8], [9, 99.65],
   [10, 99.94], [11, 99.8]

but the values are different that are plotted on the graph.

Thanks

Comment: The values plotted in the graph match the values listed underneath it. What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: I want to know the logic behind it, how it is calculating the values according to the formaula. . .y=mx + b, trend line how it is plotting on the graph

Comment: That's a good question... that I cannot answer. You will have to check the code in http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js to see how it is done. Actually, it seems like there's a more readable version here: http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js, I hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

It is not build-in, but you can try to use a [plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/22/Highcharts%20regression)